# uwp uvc camera focus unsupported

Tags: c#, uvc

uwp uvc camera focus unsupported

The code below does not apply.

```
mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(new FocusSettings { Mode = FocusMode.Auto });
await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
```

---

```
var focusControl = mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl;

if (focusControl.Supported) {
    messagetext.Text = "ok";
} else {
    messagetext.Text = "not";
}
```

The code above shows that it is not supported.
Are there any other APIs besides focusControl?
The current platform is Windows 11 and the development language is C#.

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/CameraManualControls ->I tested the example here, but my USB camera was not supported.

Camera focus control is easy in opencvsharp. How do I do this in uwp?

Comment: What platform is the code for?  What programming language?  What do you mean by "it does not apply"?   Is "uwp uvc camera focus unsupported" an exception or error message?  Please show the exception stacktrace and the code **in context**.

Comment: The platform is windows11 and the language is c#.
code ->  mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(new FocusSettings { Mode = FocusMode.Auto }); ->System.Exception: 'This request is not supported.An error message is generated.

Comment: Put the details into the question, and tag your question appropriately.  That way you might attract the attention of someone who can answer it.  (And please fix the question's styling.  It is shouty and unreadable.)